# Overlay red rectangles on top of verbatim text

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, verbatim

I am using Beamer to prepare a presentation. In some slide I need to print a great deal of verbatim text and, also, I need to draw some red rectangles on top of it.

What would be the most straightforward way to do it? I'm struggling with fancyvrb and also with tikz.

```
\documentclass[pdf]{beamer}
\usepackage{semiverbatim}

\begin{document}

\newsavebox\myv
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{IAEA phase-space file format}
\begin{lrbox}{\myv}\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{semiverbatim}
$ xxd -b -l 100 ELEKTA_PRECISE_6mv_part1.IAEAphsp
0000000: 00000001 01101001 01010011 01001000 10111111 10100011  .iSH..
0000006: 11110110 10101101 11000000 01111110 00000100 10011110  ...~..
000000c: 11000000 11101011 10001011 10110101 10111110 01110011  .....s
0000012: 01110010 10100111 10111110 11001101 11001100 01001100  r....L
0000018: 00111101 00000100 00000000 00000000 00000000 01100111  =....g
000001e: 00000000 10000000 00000001 00000001 00100011 11011111  ....#.
0000024: 01101110 00111110 00000100 10110010 10000010 00111111  n>...?
000002a: 10110101 01000001 11010000 10111110 01101011 01111111  .A..k.
0000030: 00011111 00111101 10111011 00101111 01010000 10111100  .=./P.
0000036: 11001101 11001100 01001100 00111101 00000000 00000000  ..L=..
000003c: 00000000 00000000 01100111 00000000 10000000 00000001  ..g...
0000042: 00000001 01101000 10100000 11001110 00111111 01000010  .h..?B
0000048: 10011010 10101100 10111111 00000111 00010110 01100010  .....b
000004e: 01000000 01000010 00101010 01000011 10111101 11110111  @B*C..
0000054: 11101011 00000101 00111110 11001101 11001100 01001100  ..>..L
000005a: 00111101 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 01100111  =....g
0000060: 00000000 10000000 00000001 00000001                    ....
$
\end{semiverbatim}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This is how I'd like the image to show up (notice the red rectangles):

[image]

Comment: I upvoted both answers. I accepted the first one because even though it seems a bit more complex at first sight, it doesn't require to enter the coordinates of the bounding boxes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's one possibility:

```
\documentclass[pdf]{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
  columns=fullflexible,
  escapeinside={/@}{@/}
}

\newcommand\DrawBox[2]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[red] 
  ([yshift=1.7ex,xshift=-2pt]pic cs:#1) rectangle ([yshift=-.25ex,xshift=2pt]pic cs:#2);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile,shrink=15]
\frametitle{IAEA phase-space file format}

\DrawBox{starta}{enda}
\DrawBox{startb}{endb}
\DrawBox{startc}{endc}

\begin{lstlisting}
$ xxd -b -l 100 ELEKTA_PRECISE_6mv_part1.IAEAphsp
0000000: /@\tikzmark{starta}@/00000001 01101001 01010011 01001000 10111111 10100011  .iSH..
0000006: 11110110 10101101 11000000 01111110 00000100 10011110  ...~..
000000c: 11000000 11101011 10001011 10110101 10111110 01110011  .....s
0000012: 01110010 10100111 10111110 11001101 11001100 01001100  r....L
0000018: 00111101 00000100 00000000 00000000 00000000 01100111/@\tikzmark{enda}@/  =....g
000001e: /@\tikzmark{startb}@/00000000 10000000 00000001 00000001 00100011 11011111  ....#.
0000024: 01101110 00111110 00000100 10110010 10000010 00111111  n>...?
000002a: 10110101 01000001 11010000 10111110 01101011 01111111  .A..k.
0000030: 00011111 00111101 10111011 00101111 01010000 10111100  .=./P.
0000036: 11001101 11001100 01001100 00111101 00000000 00000000/@\tikzmark{endb}@/  ..L=..
000003c: /@\tikzmark{startc}@/00000000 00000000 01100111 00000000 10000000 00000001  ..g...
0000042: 00000001 01101000 10100000 11001110 00111111 01000010  .h..?B
0000048: 10011010 10101100 10111111 00000111 00010110 01100010  .....b
000004e: 01000000 01000010 00101010 01000011 10111101 11110111  @B*C..
0000054: 11101011 00000101 00111110 11001101 11001100 01001100/@\tikzmark{endc}@/  ..>..L
000005a: 00111101 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 01100111  =....g
0000060: 00000000 10000000 00000001 00000001                    ....
$
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The idea is to switch to the `listings` package, since it gives the possibility to escape to LaTeX and then use the `tikzmark` library to place some marks at appropriate locations; those marks are then used to draw the frames using a simple `\DrawBox` command; the two arguments for the command are for the begin and end marks for each box.

The code needs two or three runs to stabilize.

Answer (score 7):

Here I use the `verbatimbox` package to set the verbatim content in a box in `\scriptsize` to fit on the page.  Then I use 3 nested `\stackinset`s to place the red rectangles over it.

```
\documentclass[pdf]{beamer}
\usepackage{verbatimbox, stackengine}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{IAEA phase-space file format}
\begin{verbbox}[\scriptsize]
$ xxd -b -l 100 ELEKTA_PRECISE_6mv_part1.IAEAphsp
0000000: 00000001 01101001 01010011 01001000 10111111 10100011  .iSH..
0000006: 11110110 10101101 11000000 01111110 00000100 10011110  ...~..
000000c: 11000000 11101011 10001011 10110101 10111110 01110011  .....s
0000012: 01110010 10100111 10111110 11001101 11001100 01001100  r....L
0000018: 00111101 00000100 00000000 00000000 00000000 01100111  =....g
000001e: 00000000 10000000 00000001 00000001 00100011 11011111  ....#.
0000024: 01101110 00111110 00000100 10110010 10000010 00111111  n>...?
000002a: 10110101 01000001 11010000 10111110 01101011 01111111  .A..k.
0000030: 00011111 00111101 10111011 00101111 01010000 10111100  .=./P.
0000036: 11001101 11001100 01001100 00111101 00000000 00000000  ..L=..
000003c: 00000000 00000000 01100111 00000000 10000000 00000001  ..g...
0000042: 00000001 01101000 10100000 11001110 00111111 01000010  .h..?B
0000048: 10011010 10101100 10111111 00000111 00010110 01100010  .....b
000004e: 01000000 01000010 00101010 01000011 10111101 11110111  @B*C..
0000054: 11101011 00000101 00111110 11001101 11001100 01001100  ..>..L
000005a: 00111101 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 01100111  =....g
0000060: 00000000 10000000 00000001 00000001                    ....
$
\end{verbbox}
\stackinset{c}{2pt}{c}{58pt}{\textcolor{red}{\framebox(230,46){}}}{%
\stackinset{c}{2pt}{c}{10pt}{\textcolor{red}{\framebox(230,46){}}}{%
\stackinset{c}{2pt}{c}{-38pt}{\textcolor{red}{\framebox(230,46){}}}{%
\theverbbox}}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]