# Escaping within lstlisting adds a space

Tags: tikz-pgf, listings

I'm basing my code on [Overlay red rectangles on top of verbatim text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/177470/overlay-red-rectangles-on-top-of-verbatim-text) in order to grab draw arrows over the source code.

I've successfully incorporated the solution into my code, however one problem appears: when I escape within `lstlisting`, it inserts a space in the source code.

## LaTeX source

```
\begin{lstlisting}
@Template(`This is a /@\tikz[remember picture] \node [] (view-left) {};@/{{ value }}/@\tikz[remember picture] \node [] (view-right) {};@/.`)
class Component {
  value/@\tikz[remember picture] \node [] (code-right) {};@/ = 21
}
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node (view) at ($(view-left)!.5!(view-right)$) {};
  \draw (view.south) edge [bend left] (code-right.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

## Result

[image: The rendered result which shows additional spaces where escaping was done.]

## Problem

- There are two spaces between `a` and `{{` in the template (one was intentional, there's an extra one).
- A space between `}}` in `.` in template.
- Double space after `value` in the code.

Why do they appear and how can I get rid of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of enclosing the `tikzpicture` in a box of width 0, as [@egreg suggests](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/447835/121799), it is probably easier to work with overlay, which is made for this, or to use the `tizkmark` library.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
  columns=fullflexible,
  escapeinside={/@}{@/}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
@Template(`This is a /@\tikz[remember picture,overlay] \node [] (view-left) {};@/{{ value }}/@\tikz[remember picture,overlay] \node [] (view-right) {};@/.`)
class Component {
  value/@\tikz[remember picture,overlay] \node [] (code-right) {};@/ = 21
}
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node (view) at ($(view-left)!.5!(view-right)$) {};
  \draw (view.south) edge [bend left] (code-right.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{lstlisting}
@Template(`This is a /@\tikzmark{view-left}@/{{ value }}/@\tikzmark{view-right}@/.`)
class Component {
  value/@\tikzmark{code-right}@/ = 21
}
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node (view) at ($(pic cs:view-left)!.5!(pic cs:view-right)$) {};
  \draw (view.south) to[bend left] ([yshift=-2mm]pic cs:code-right);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Enclose the Ti*k*Z picture in a zero width box:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible,
  escapeinside={/@}{@/},
}
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{%
  \makebox[0pt]{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \node [] (#1) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
@Template(`This is a /@\foo{view-left}@/{{ value }}/@\foo{view-right}@/.`)
class Component {
  value/@\foo{code-right}@/ = 21
}
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node (view) at ($(view-left)!.5!(view-right)$) {};
  \draw (view.south) edge [bend left] (code-right.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]